'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command React Native 0.72.7
I'm creating a fresh react native project and followed all the steps from their official docs: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup but it says that 'gradlew.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command:

and I even followed this solution: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/1220 and installed SDK commandline tools but running react native doctor still shows that i don't have Android SDK:


Solved this by doing a fresh install of Android Studio
